# Windows form inside console application or vice versa

Tags: c#

I have this task given to me and have no idea how to approach it.. Everywhere online says that this isn't possible without .dll or mocking.

> The server, when launched with an argument of –w should open a windowed interface that
>   permits an operator to control the functions of the server. If launched with no arguments it
>   should operate as previously specified in part 1

(part 1 is a console application) 
I don't know if I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: Could the console application perhaps check for a `-w` and, if found, launch a 2nd application ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're seeing on-line that this isn't possible. Every Windows Forms application has a `Main` method, you just need to modify it a bit.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        File.WriteAllText("hello.txt", "foo");
    }
    else
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

I added the `string[] args` argument and then check it. I'm not checking for `-w`, I'm just checking for any old argument, but you should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score -1):

It's absolutely not impossible. Just add reference to System.Windows.Forms, add it in the using clause, and go from here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleWindow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Contains("-w"))
            {
                Form1 f1 = new Form1();
                f1.ShowDialog();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```